# How can I get the Month Name from Archive?

Tags: archives

I have created an archive page.. where i wanted to display which archive month is displaying.. how can I display the month name?

Comment: Jeremy has provided a solid answer. Did his approach work for you? If so, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get the month of the current archive page you'll have to use `single_month_title`. The following code will output " August 2014" (notice the space before the month)

```
<?php single_month_title(' ') ?>
```

Without a space before the month:

```
<?php echo trim(single_month_title(' ',false)) ?>
```

*Read more: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_month_title*

Answer (score 2):

To display the Month, place this in your template where you want the date to show:

```
<?php the_date('F m'); ?>
```

That will show the full month name and the day. If you just want an abbreviation of the month like Aug. you would use:

```
<?php the_date('M.'); ?>
```

Place in front of `<?php the_the_permalink(); ?>`

Here's a complete example using it with the title:

```
<h2><?php the_date('M.'); ?> <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```